# Microsoft Graph Sharepoint subsite list

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible get list and items of a subsite in [SharePoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint) using the Microsoft Graph?

There is a way to [get a subsite](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subsites_list) but not the items of a subsite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a subsite, you can make subsequent queries by using the identifier of that subsite.

For instance, if I fetch `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites`, I can see the subsites available, each of which has an id.

I can then make a subsequent query to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<subsite id>/lists` to fetch the lists for this sub-site.

It is also possible to use [OData query options](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752359) and request the 'lists' for each sub-site *expanded* in the request to get subsites. I can make a call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites?$expand=lists` and see entries for each of their sub-sites, and also their lists.

Comment: Thank, this works. tried this before and it didn't work, but now it did.